# Passing escaped color values to mixins

Tags: less

Using less's variables I have a current styleguide which helps site's look remain consistent.

```
@black: #000000;
@darkGrey:#343434;
@grey: #a1a1a1;
@lightGrey: #e5e5e5;
@white: #ffffff;
```

I am also using a parametric mixin like so

```
.curve (@color: white){background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none' width='100%25' height='100%25' %3E%3Cpath fill='@{color}' stroke='transparent' d=' M 0,100 C 20,0 80,100 100,0 L 100,100 '%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Which outputs a small horizontal s shaped curve.

There are two problems that are currently happening. Since this is using url() the colors either have to be single words, or escaped hex colors. The second is being unable to use my variables on the mixin.

So:

```
.curve() // works
.curve('%23a1a1a1') // works
.curve(black) // works - using css's own colors
.curve(@grey) // doesn't work - # not encoded to %23
.curve(escape(@grey)) // doesn't work

@color:escape(@grey);
.curve('@{color}'); // works
```

I'm at a slight loss, and feel there's a simple solution that I'm missing. Would it be better to have multiple mixins with default values? Can I simply use my current mixin (hopefully with the variable)?

Comment: `.curve(%(escape(@grey)));`

Comment: And why don't you simply force escaping *within* that mixin, e.g. [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/12d447f50d7a946d064100c98529d0d9) would work just fine for either color format.

Comment: Was just unhappy with my current solution, and was looking for a more elegant solution, of which yours is!